Conditionally add property to object
I wish to add ingress rules to a security group, and I need to allow users to do this through variables while specifying only the name, description and either a cidr_block or a security_group_id.
I have added a variable, set a value for that variable, and am attempting to create a local variable that I can then use in my (specifically within an EKS module definition).
However, I'm encountering an error Null values are not allowed for this attribute value. when the aforementioned local variable is created, which I believe is because variable in within the EKS module aren't nullable.
So given the following code, how can I amend my local variable to totally ignore either cidr_block or security_group_id if they are not specified, rather than setting the value to null?

From variables.tf
variable "ingress_rules" {
  description = "Ingress rules to add to the application security group."
  type = set(object({
    name                     = string
    description              = string
    cidr_block               = optional(string)
    source_security_group_id = optional(string)
  }))
  default = []
}

From tfvars file
ingress_rules = [
  {
    name        = "dev_vpc"
    description = "Dev VPC"
    cidr_block  = "99.99.99.99/28"
  },
  {
    name                     = "cicd_sg"
    description              = "CI/CD server security group"
    source_security_group_id = "sg-00000000000000000"
  }
]

From main.tf
locals {
  ingress_rules = {
    for ingress in var.ingress_rules : ingress.name => {
      description              = ingress.description
      type                     = "ingress"
      protocol                 = "tcp"
      from_port                = 443
      to_port                  = 443
      cidr_blocks              = [lookup(ingress, "cidr_block", null)]
      source_security_group_id = [lookup(ingress, "security_group_id", null)]
    }
  }
}

Full error message
╷
│ Error: Null value found in list
│ 
│   with module.eks[0].aws_security_group_rule.cluster["cicd_sg"],
│   on .terraform/modules/eks/main.tf line 210, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "cluster":
│  210:   cidr_blocks              = lookup(each.value, "cidr_blocks", null)
│ 
│ Null values are not allowed for this attribute value.


Are these tf files from your code or from the module?

That is my TF code.

Ok, cidr_blocks probably expects input of type list(string) so you might want to try with something like cidr_blocks = [ingress.cidr_block != null ? ingress.cidr_block : "" ].

@MarkoE Modify that to ingress.cidr_block == null ? [] : [ingress.cidr_block] and probably answer. Also though the original type is optional(string) and only ever will be one cidr block or ingress rule, and so could also remove the list constructor entirely to be even easier and cleaner: cidr_block = lookup(ingress, "cidr_block", null) where key is renamed for clarity. It seems like a for expression or coalesce could assist here, but I do not see how. You suggested answer first so I will not borrow from it for my own answer.

@MatthewSchuchard Please do, I'm pretty sure your answer will have even more valuable information than mine!

Thanks for the feedback both. I have to lookup ingress.cird_block because it's optional and there is not default. Therefore, I've changed my code to lookup(ingress, "cidr_block", null) != null ? [ingress.cidr_block] : null and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks again.

In general the value you want for unset complex types would be an empty constructor e.g. [] or {}. Expanding on the suggestion by MarkoE arrives at the following solution:
cidr_blocks              = ingress.cidr_block == null ? [] : [ingress.cidr_block]
source_security_group_id = ingress.source_security_group_id == null ? [] : [ingress.source_security_group_id]

Alternatively your original type is optional(string) and therefore a list type in your locals would be unnecessary, and you can remove the constructor:
cidr_blocks              = lookup(ingress, "cidr_block", null)
source_security_group_id = lookup(ingress, "security_group_id", null)

However, while the usage of these values is unspecified in the question, I would imagine these are for inputs to the terraform-aws-eks module requiring either list(string or set(string) types for the values. In that case the above suggestion would be invalid. In that situation you could also:
cidr_blocks              = ingress.cidr_block == null ? null : [ingress.cidr_block]
source_security_group_id = ingress.source_security_group_id == null ? null : [ingress.source_security_group_id]

Note the coalesce function is somewhat relevant here, but I believe cannot improve the code. I would be super interested in seeing a clever solution with it though.
